# How to go back to top of loop after finishing?

Tags: python, selenium, loops

When visiting some websites with selenium there are times where the page doesn't load correctly. So I want to write a code that checks if the website loaded correctly by searching for a particular button. If it can't find the button it needs to refresh until it finds the button and if the code does find the button it needs to execute the rest of the code.

So for example: Button not there: >>> refresh >>> (checks again if button is not there) Button not there >>> refresh >>> (checks again if button is not there) Button is there >>> rest of code

The loop that I currently have looks like this but after refreshing the loop doesn't restart and runs the else: function.
So the question is how do I make a loop that restarts the loop after it refreshes.

```
while not (driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "button")):
    driver.refresh()
else: 
    Rest of code
```

Help would be much appreciated, thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "I tried to do it like this but after doing either driver.refresh() or find different button it keeps doing it and ofcourse not going back to the while not loop." I can't understand this description of the problem at all. Please take a deep breath and try to write more clearly.

Comment: If you enclose everything in another while loop then it will continue to loop after look for button>rest of code. However, your problem is not clear. Some more context would be useful.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Thanks for letting me know I added some details.

Comment: @yuuuu Thanks for letting me know I added some details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have an infinite while loop, and an if condition with `find_elements`, Please note that `find_elements` does not return any exception, it returns a list of web elements or either 0.

**Code:**

```
while True:
    try:
        if len(driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "xpath of the button")) >0:
            print("Button is present, since find elements list is non empty")
            # execute the code, may be click on the button or whatever it is.
            #make sure to exit from infinite loop as well
            break
        else:
            driver.refresh()
            #may be put some delay here to let button available to click again.
    except:
        print("There was some problem trying to find the button element, tearing it down")
        break
```

Comment: Will the code check again if the button is there after refreshing

Comment: What do you think? it's in infinite loop and only breaks if the button is available in if block. if not it will keep on running.